# ¿Cómo obtener las llaves foraneas de una base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo una base de datos que no es de mi autoria, intento eliminar de una tabla pero obtengo este error,

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK". The conflict occurred in database "BASE", table "Table".
The statement has been terminated.
```

Quiero saber si es posible mediante un select puedo obtener las llaves foraneas de esa base de datos.

uso SQL SERVER 2014

Si Ocupan las tablas haganmelo saber en un comentario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes obtener las llaves foráneas (foreign keys) de la base de datos a través de las tablas de sistema. En concreto la tabla `sys.foreign_keys` lista todas las llaves foráneas de la base de datos.

Esta consulta muestra el nombre de todas las claves foráneas y las tablas que referencian:

```
SELECT FK.name, PFK.name AS parentTable, RFK.name AS referencedTable
FROM sys.foreign_keys FK
INNER JOIN sys.objects PFK ON PFK.object_id = FK.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects RFK ON RFK.object_id = FK.referenced_object_id
```

También puedes utilizar el procedimiento almacenado `sp_fkeys` para obtener las claves foráneas de una tabla determinada:

```
sp_fkeys 'Table'
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.